How to show $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{m-1}{2}\rfloor$ is equal to this expression?
I am trying to show equality between the two expressions
$$\frac {\lfloor{\frac n 2}\rfloor(\lfloor{\frac n 2}\rfloor - 1)\lfloor{\frac m 2}\rfloor(\lfloor{\frac m 2}\rfloor - 1)} 4 + \frac {\lfloor{\frac n 2}\rfloor(\lfloor{\frac n 2}\rfloor - 1)\lceil{\frac m 2}\rceil(\lceil{\frac m 2}\rceil - 1)} 4 + \frac {\lceil{\frac n 2}\rceil(\lceil{\frac n 2}\rceil - 1)\lfloor{\frac m 2}\rfloor(\lfloor{\frac m 2}\rfloor - 1)} 4 + \frac {\lceil{\frac n 2}\rceil(\lceil{\frac n 2}\rceil - 1)\lceil{\frac m 2}\rceil(\lceil{\frac m 2}\rceil - 1)} 4$$ and $$Z(m, n)=\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{m-1}{2}\rfloor$$
for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$.
The reason why is that I am studying Zarankiewicz's Conjecture, and the first expression I gave was my attempt to come up with an expression equal to the number of crossings of the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,m}$when drawn according to Zarankiewicz's construction, and the second expression is the expression said to be the actual amount of crossings in such a drawing. I suspect my expression is correct as there is equality between these expressions for the values of $n,m$ which I tested.
So how can I show equality? I see of course that the first expression is equal to $\frac {(\lfloor{\frac n 2}\rfloor(\lfloor{\frac n 2}\rfloor - 1) + \lceil{\frac n 2}\rceil(\lceil{\frac n 2}\rceil - 1))(\lfloor{\frac m 2}\rfloor(\lfloor{\frac m 2}\rfloor - 1) + \lceil{\frac m 2}\rceil(\lceil{\frac m 2}\rceil - 1))} 4$, but got stuck trying to find further meaningful simplifications.

Perhaps split to four cases by parity of $m$ and $n$, the floor/ceiling functions will go away.

There're many ways to show this equality.  I've just shown one such way below.
From the symmetry appearing in your last expression, you could guess we want to prove $$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor-1\right) + \left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil\left(\left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil-1\right) = 2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor \tag{1}$$
From a simple instance of Prove that $\left\lceil \frac{n}{m} \right\rceil =\left \lfloor \frac{n+m-1}{m} \right\rfloor$, we can turn those ceilings into floors by $$\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil = \left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}-1\right\rfloor+1 = \left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor + 1$$
to see $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor-1\right) + \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor = 2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor.$$
This equation, in turn, is algebraically equivalent to
$$\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor\right)\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor - 1\right) = 0$$
so it suffices to show that $$\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor \in \{0,1\}$$
I'll leave the proof of this to you.

Here we follow the proposal from @Sil. Due to nice symmetries it is sufficient to consider just two instead of four cases. We consider the three arithmetic functions: $f_1, f_2, f_3$ with
\begin{align*}
f_1(k)&=\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor-1\right)\\
f_2(k)&=\left\lceil\frac{k}{2}\right\rceil\left(\left\lceil\frac{k}{2}\right\rceil-1\right)\\
f_3(k)&=\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{k-1}{2}\right\rfloor
\end{align*}
Thanks to OP's simplified representation we have to show
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{f_1(n)+f_2(n)}{2}\cdot\frac{f_1(m)+f_2(m)}{2}=f_3(n)f_3(m)\qquad\qquad m,n\in\mathbb{N}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Due to the symmetry in (1) it is sufficient to show
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{f_1(n)+f_2(n)}{2}=f_3(n)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
which we do in tabular form for even $n=2N$ and odd $n=2N+1$.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c|l|c}
n&\frac{1}{2}\left(f_1(n)\qquad\qquad+f_2(n)\right)&f_3(n)\\
&&\\
&\frac{1}{2}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor-1\right)
+\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil\left(\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil-1\right)\right)
&\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor\\
&&\\
\hline\\
2N&\frac{1}{2}\left(N(N-1)\qquad+N(N-1)\right)&N(N-1)\\
&&\\
2N+1&\frac{1}{2}\left(N(N-1)\qquad+(N+1)N\right)&N^2\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}
and (2) and due to symmetry also (1) follow.

